# how to run a .net core web API as Linux daemon

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-services, daemon

i have created a .net core web API then add the flowing package
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices;
to my `program.cs`
then write the flowing code in `program.cs`

[image]

then copy the whole project to Linux Ubuntu and published it with the flowing command

`dotnet publish -c release -r ubuntu.16.04-x64`

then copied the created publish folder to :  `/etc/SampleWebservice`

and copy the .dll file to  :     `/usr/share/dotnet`

and create the `.service` file like this

```
     [Unit]  
     Description=Dotnet Core WebApi Demo service  

     [Service]  
     ExecStart=/usr/share/dotnet/weba.dll  
     WorkingDirectory=/etc/SampleWebservice/publish/  
     User=dotnetuser  
     Group=dotnetuser  
     Restart=on-failure  
     SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-webapi-service  
     PrivateTemp=true  

    [Install]  
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then run these commands

```
Sudu systemctl daemon-reload
Sudo systemctl enable servicename
Sudo systemctl start servicename
Sudo systemctl status servicename
```

and i got the flowing status
[daemon status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08rkD.png)

it works fine on windows and install as a windows service and everything is OK but does not work on Linux.
can anyone tell me what i have done wrong?
is it from the packages or the config code in `program.cs`
or is it the `.service` file.
i am really stuck and i will appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you please change the `ExecStart=/usr/share/dotnet/weba.dll ` to `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet  <the-path-to-main-dll>`?

Comment: i changed it to this and it did not work`[Unit]
Description=Dotnet Core WebApi Demo service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /etc/SampleWebservice/publish/weba.dll
WorkingDirectory=/etc/SampleWebservice/publish/
User=dotnetuser
Group=dotnetuser
Restart=on-failure
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-webapi-service
PrivateTemp=true
  
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target`

Comment: What did you get by `journalctl -u   <the-service-name>`?

Comment: -- Logs begin at Mon 2019-12-30 23:18:39 PST, end at Tue 2019-12-31 01:47:20 PST
Dec 30 23:18:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Dotnet Core WebApi Demo service.
Dec 30 23:18:46 ubuntu systemd[951]: dotnet-webapi-service.service: Failed at st
Dec 30 23:18:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: dotnet-webapi-service.service: Main process e
: dotnet-webapi-service.service: Unit entered f
Dec 30 23:18:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: dotnet-webapi-service.service: Failed with re
 dotnet-webapi-service.service: Service hold-o
 Stopped Dotnet Core WebApi Demo service.
 Started Dotnet Core WebApi Demo service.

Comment: Dec 30 23:18:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Dotnet Core WebApi Demo service.
Dec 30 23:18:46 ubuntu systemd[951]: dotnet-webapi-service.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/SampleWebservice/publish/weba.dll: Permis
Dec 30 23:18:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: dotnet-webapi-service.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Dec 30 23:18:46 ubuntu systemd[1]: dotnet-webapi-service.service: Unit entered failed state.
 dotnet-webapi-service.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 dotnet-webapi-service.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.

Comment: Seems "Permission denied". See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209097

Comment: could you describe a little about .service file element or tell me a good reference to learn

Comment: could you describe a little about .service file element or tell me a good reference to learn

Comment: 1. "Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/SampleWebservice/publish/weba.dll: Permis" This error information seems `Permission denied`. I'm not totally sure about that. But to test whether it is a permission issue, you could change the `User=root` temporarily. If that's the case,  it means you need grant the permissions to `dotnetuser`. Don't forget to change the `User=dotnetuser` when this issue has been confirmed